# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp with transparent background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm implementing a fairly standard `UIView` animation, using `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`. The basic idea is that I have a folder on the screen covered with a stack of pages, and as I change from page to page I use the curl up animation. Each page is a subview that takes up about 70% of the screen so that the clipboard is still visible in the background.

This animation all works fine, that problem is that even though each "page" (which is a separate `UIViewController` & `UIView`) has a transparent background, the page background becomes visible during the page curl. It's only slightly visible, like a black background with an alpha of 0.1. But it ruins the effect.

Any ideas? This is for a private application that will not be distributed on the app store, so private APIs are ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the size of the `view` of your page view controller to be exactly the size of your page image.  It looks from your included image that your page is also rotated.  You can apply a rotation to your view to match this rotation.  Here is part of the code that I used to achieve the effect in the screenshot:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

CGRect pageViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 586);
self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;
self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/30);

[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

[image]